# In laravel update image file without using controller

Tags: javascript, laravel, methods, directory, fetch

i am having a problem with my code.
i have a canvas image and i want insert markers with text and picture for "n" element, because i would like the user choose how many point insert in it.
So, for the text I have done, because i sum the previous text with new and use a separator as "$", then in Model Member i split it and display it for every point.
But, for the file is different because I want to update these in folder path(`/public/images`), but doens't work. Below, some parts about my code:

```js
var loadFile = function(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = reader.result;
    var file = event.target.files[0]; 
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    var extension = file.name.split('.').pop();
    filename = Date.now() + '.' + extension;
    
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( file ) );
    
    fetch("/public/images/",{
        method:"POST",
        headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: data
    })
    .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
    .then(function(data){ alert( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
```

The result in console is:`"POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/images/ 404 (Not Found)"`
I understood that the move of file is not happens.

for the text:

```js
for (var k = 0; k < Markers.length; k++) {
    commentinegative=commentinegative+Markers[k].comment.toString()+'*';
```

Some ideas? thank you.

Comment: Try using `/images/` instead of `/public/images/` in your fetch. `public` is already the root (`127.0.0.1:8000`)